# Jeep Grand Cherokee: what is this plate sticking out of the undercarriage

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee, underbody

I'm looking to buy a 2014 Jeep Grand Cherokee and during the visual inspection I noticed this plate sticking out of the undercarriage. Everything is more or less the same level on the undercarriage except this plate and it also looks weirdly bent.

Is it in a normal condition or is there cause for concern?

[image: Jeep undercarriage]

Comment: Heat shield for the catalytic converter, looks like it got bent down a bit.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @Moab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Heat shield for the catalytic converter, looks like it got bent down a bit.

Comment: Thanks, any concerns with continuing with it in this bent shape?
Likely causes? Guess scraping against a rock or something?
Should I avoid the car?

Comment: Its no big deal, it can be easily bent back into position. I have no clue how it got that way.